# Sql execute multiple update statements at the same time and return each execution result?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am developing an order system which can receive all or part of the goods.

For example, the order contains three items: A, B, and C.

I will try to execute the SQL that deducts the inventory quantity, and if it succeeds, I will receive the Item. For example:

```
update itemTable set qty = qty-1 where id=A and qty-1>=0 //Success
update itemTable set qty = qty-1 where id=B and qty-1>=0 //Failed
update itemTable set qty = qty-1 where id=C and qty-1>=0 //Success
```

Then the order system will accept AC and reject B.

**What i do now: Execute sql multiple times**

I am executing it statement by statement, which requires three connections to the database. pseudo code like the following:

```
foreach(var item in order.items){
      //Execute sql deducting inventory quantity
     var affectedRows = ExecuteSql("update itemTable set qty = qty-1 where id={item.id} and qty-1>=0")
     if(affectedRows> 0){
        item.Accepted = true;
     }else{
        item.Accepted = false;
    }
}
```

**What i want: Execute once, return all results**

Is there a way to execute three statements at once and return their respective results? For example, pseudo code like the following:

```
var sqlStatements = "";
foreach(var item in order.items){
   //Execute sql deducting inventory quantity
   sqlStatements += "update itemTable set qty = qty-1 where id={item.id} and qty-1>=0;"         
}
var result = ExecuteSql(sqlStatements); //Execute once,get all results
foreach(var r in result){
   if(r.successed){
      order.items.find(r.id).Accepted = true;
   }else{
      order.items.find(r.id).Accepted = false;
   }
}
```

Or is there a better way to implement this logic?

Comment: Need to know what version of SQL Server.  If it's 2016+ then a JSON based approach is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause:

```
create table @ids (
    id varchar(255)  -- or whatever
);

update itemTable
    output inserted.id into @ids
    set qty = it.qty - v.diff
    from (values ('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('C', 2)
         ) v(id, diff)
    where itemTable.id = v.id and itemTable.qty >= v.diff

select *
from @ids;
```

You can then select the ids from `@ids` -- or whatever table you

Comment: This is what I want, thank you so much! !
I have two more questions:
1. Will there be performance problems if I do this frequently?
2. Do I have to use different table names for concurrent operations?

Comment: @IanWong . . . Obviously, putting a load on the server would slow things down, but `output` is not really going to add much to a load already using `update`s.  And for your second question, the table variable is local to your code block, so you can run the same code in different sessions.